# How can I alter Scipy's Convolve2D() to ignore array values that are 0?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, convolution

**Context:** I'm implementing a cellular automata simulator for snowflake growth which depends on a set of nearest neighbor rules. There are 4 arrays which represent at each x,y a specific state value for the cell at that position. The most intensive operations in the program are all convolutions on those numpy arrays which are around 1000x1000 cells in size using a 3x3 kernel (with symmetric boundaries) which update a cell's state value with the sum of it and its neighbors.

I found that cells that have a 0 value in the array being convolved must always have a 0 value in the output. At the moment I have to do this manually by applying an element wise matrix multiplication to the convolution output with an array of the same shape filled with 1s and 0s. I've looked at some questions on the platform which discuss missing values and the use of NaN but from my limited experience with Python this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. The code in question currently looks like this

```
#kernel -> some 3x3 kernel
#d_mass -> #some 1000x1000 array whose 0 cells must remain 0 after convolution

d_mass = convolve2d(d_mass, kernel, boundary='symm', mode='same') * arr_ones_zeros
```

**What I want to know:** Is there a way I can get scipy's convolve2d() to ignore cells with value == 0 or introduce a sort of conditional so that they automatically have a 0 value in the output, avoiding the unnecessary dot product calculation? Other similarly efficient solutions are also welcome :)

Comment: You can set those values to 0 with `output[input==0] = 0`. Any other solution you come up with is likely going to slow down things.